# inconsistent capitals in sha256

Tags: hashsum

I've downloaded a windows 10 OS and tested the sha256, [compared to what they report](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO) for English international 64 bit (left hand side):

```
[ 06FD4A512C5F3E8D16F77CA909C4F20110329B8CDD5AD101E2AFC0D58B06D416 = 06fd4a512c5f3e8d16f77ca909c4f20110329b8cdd5ad101e2afc0d58b06d416 ] && echo "true"
```

after testing I noticed the capitalization is inverted. I always thought sha distinguishes capitals, but maybe I'm wrong. [This SO post agrees though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892053/is-sha-256-case-insensitive).

All SHA hashes are stored as capitals in the windows page.

Should I be bothered by that? I don't find any report regarding capitals in the man page for the sha256 command.

The way I evaluated the hash is using `sha256sum <filename>`.

Comment: You can provide a hash to sha256sum and tell it to check for that instead of doing your own string comparison. I'd expect any sane tool to ignore capitalisation in hex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A SHA hash is usually given as the hexadecimal representation of the calculated hash; since it’s a hexadecimal number, case doesn’t matter.

If you store the hash in a file, followed by two spaces and the name of the file you wish to verify, you can use `sha256sum -c` to verify the hash, and it will ignore case in the hash itself (but not the hashed content):

```
$ printf "%s  %s\n" 06FD4A512C5F3E8D16F77CA909C4F20110329B8CDD5AD101E2AFC0D58B06D416 windows.iso > windows.sha
$ sha256sum -c windows.sha
```